# XFCE dusk list color bug

Tags: gtk, themes, xfce

I have the following problem with lists using xfce dusk. This does not only apply to firefox, but to lists in other programs as well, such as PyChess for instance.

Does anyone know what I have to add to the .gtkrc (or perhaps one of the .gtk3 files) of the XFCE dusk theme to finally get something readable out of this?

[image: Here is an image showing what I'm talking about]

Comment: Which version of gtk do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out about xfce-dusk-gtk3, the reworked version of xfce-dusk that supports both: gtk2 (with the .gtkrc or .gtkrc-2.0 conf file), and gtk3 (CSS based)

Just extract and put into either:
- your local .themes
- /usr/local/share/themes
- /usr/share/themes

Comment: I ducked it for you; here's the URL: http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Xfce-dusk-gtk3?content=141404